# Reading from .txt file skips "\n" character

Tags: c#, monogame

So I am trying to read from a text document and use all the text as one string.

My text document contains the following line:

> 000\n010\n000

I use this to read from the file:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("map.txt");
string mapString = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I then use the read line to generate a map in Monogame. I run in to a problem though, which breaks my game. What I think happens, is that the reader reads:

> 000\n010\n000

as

> 000010000

since it works when I just set

```
string mapString = "000\n010\n000";
```

Does anyone know a solution / had the same problem?

Comment: can you not just use `ReadAllLines method along with string.Replace method` to replace the `"\n"` with `" "` you are aware that `"\n and \r"` are recognized Return Characters and New Line in C#

Comment: use System.IO.ReadAllText(path) ... read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why do you think the reader reads it as `"000010000"`? On my computer, `StreamReader` reads `"000\n010\n000"` just as it is on the disk. But it also reads `"000\r\n010\r\n000"` just as *it* is on the disk. Have you confirmed with a binary editor that the file is what you think it is?

Comment: I tried File.ReadAllText didn't work either.

I am 99% it reads it as 000010000 since the generated map looks like this:
http://i.imgur.com/pMVeB5Z.png
When I read from file.

This is what it looks like when I set the string inside of the code: http://i.imgur.com/aLpPW2S.png

Comment: @Hunniche That image doesn't mean anything to me. I'd pop in a breakpoint and check the string in the debugger, and open the file in a binary editor to see what the bytes really are ("File | Open" in VS, select the file, click the down arrow on the "Open" button, and select "Open With..." from the little menu that pops up).

Comment: You probably don't want to use StreamReader.  Get the raw bytes from FileStream.  You are going to run into Windows and .NET String conventions like others have mentioned.  In Windows a line ends with "\r\n"

Comment: matt-dot-net, yeah that could be the reason. Dan Puzey, it contains litterally "000\n010\n000" without the quotes.

Comment: So the file actually has a backslash followed by the letter n in it? Or do the \n above mean that it is a linefeed?

Comment: That it actually has a backslash followed by the letter n in it. "000\n010\n000" without the quotations is literally the content of the text document.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, i've never seen that the streamreader skipped linebreaks (\n or \r\n)

you can check your file byte for byte:

```
  var test = File.ReadAllBytes("map.txt");

  if (test.All(b => char.IsNumber((char)b))) throw new Exception("only numbers found!");

  if (!test.Any(b => b == '\n')) throw new Exception("no linebrakes found!");

  Console.WriteLine("--- char stats ---");
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", test.GroupBy(c => c).OrderBy(g=>-g.Count()).Select(g => (g.Key < ' ' ? "0x" + g.Key.ToString("x").PadLeft(2,'0') : "   " + (char)g.Key) + " - count: " + g.Count())));
```

result (on correct file):

```
   0 - count: 8
0x0a - count: 2
   1 - count: 1
```

0x0a is the hex-coded '\n'

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the tips from the comments, I got on the tracks to add a breakpoint to check the mapString after it had been set by the file.

It gave me this string:

```
mapString = "000\\n010\\n010";
```

so it added an extra "\" before each "\n" for some reason.

To fix this I used a bit of a hacky fix and just used:

```
String.Replace("\\n", "\n");
```

Thanks for getting me on the right track.

Comment: No, "it" didn't add a backslash. You were just lying to us about what was in the file. Or horribly misunderstanding it. It looks like it had backslashes followed by lower-case 'n', when it was supposed to be newlines instead. When you see "\\n" in the debugger or a string literal, '\\' is a single escaped backslash character.

Comment: The "some reason" is that `\n` is what's know as an escape code, valid _within the syntax of .NET_ (though this one is also prevalent elsewhere) that indicates a newline character. That is to say: if you create a string literal in code, the two-character sequence `\n` will be interpreted as a single newline character in the string itself. A text file that contains `\n` instead of a newline character is just that: a backslash followed by an `n`.

Comment: The reason the "added" backslash appears is that, because the backslash character represents the start of an escape sequence, the only way to represent an _actual_ backslash within a .NET string is to make the backslash itself an escape sequence: two backslashes in code represents a single backslash in the resulting string.

Comment: Why would I lie about that @EdPlunkett? Here is a screenshot of the file + the string at the breakpoint. http://i.imgur.com/JTC6qkX.png

Comment: @Hunniche I haven't a clue why you claimed it was "000\n010\n000" in your question, but your screenshot shows "000\\n010\\n000". You tell me.

Comment: @EdPlunkett What do you mean I claimed it was "000\n010\n000"? It has always been "000\n010\n000" in the file, that never changed. I was unsure what the program read it as, however. I said that it could be reading it as "000010000" but I wasn't sure.